# WSO2 Api manager - Business plan not working

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-appm

I'm trying to learn how to use WSO2 API Manager. I've created an API in the Publisher and I've created a customized business plan policy, setting 10 requests per minute.

Then I've created a user with the role of subscriber, and I've subscribed to the API.

When I try out the API, and exceed the 10 requests the Api still works, I don't get the message "Message throttled out". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you use the created business plan when subscribing to the API from an application?

Comment: yes I've used my custom business plan. I've followed this guide https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/tutorials/scenarios/scenario8-rate-limiting/

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm that you have done the following tasks in order.

1. Created an API with default security (Not an unauthenticated API)
2. Created a subscription policy with 10 requests per minutes.
3. Added this subscription policy from publisher UI as a business plan.
4. Subscribed to this API from an application in devportal using the same business plan?
5. Invoked the API more than 10 within a minute, using a token generated from the same application in point 3?

Comment: yes I did all all of this